# Four-dimensional vector bundles over $S^4$, intuition?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I know that $\pi_3(SO(4)) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. We can choose an explicit identification as follows: given $(i, j) \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have a map $\phi: S^3 \to SO(4)$ which sends a unit quaternion $u$ to the map$$\phi(u): \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4, \text{ }\phi(u)(x) = u^i xu^j.$$

My question is, what is the crux/intuition behind all this?

Comment: If you are asking about Milnor's exotic sphere, then in the last chapter of Characteristic Classes by Milnor & Stasheff, there is an alternative construction. The main idea is by choosing such i and j, we are being able to control the Euler class and 1st Pontrjagin class of the vector bundle. We want to keep Euler class to be 1 so that when looking at sphere bundle we have a homotopy sphere(which is a homeomorphic sphere by Smale), and the extra room for the Pontrjagin class can change the Milnor invariant.

Answer (score 15):

It probably helps if you notice that the unit quaternions are isomorphic to $SU(2)$, and the unit quaternions act as rotations on the quaternions by both left and right multiplication.  So, we get a homomorphism

$$ p: SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SO(4) $$

It's easy to check that this is onto and that the kernel is $\pm (1,1)$.  So, we get a double cover $p: SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SO(4)$, which therefore induces an isomorphism

$$ \pi_3(p) : \pi_3(SU(2) \times SU(2)) \to \pi_3(SO(4)) $$

Since $SU(2)$ is a 3-sphere, $\pi_3(SU(2)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so

$$ \pi_3(SO(4)) \cong \pi_3(SU(2) \times SU(2)) \cong \pi_3(SU(2)) \oplus \pi_3(SU(2)) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} $$

But if you take the argument I gave and carefully follow all the details, you can get the explicit identification of $\pi_3(SO(4))$ with $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ described in the original question!  For this it helps to notice that the map

$$ f_i : SU(2) \to SU(2) $$

given by

$$ f_i(u) = u^i $$

has [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#From_Sn_to_Sn) $i$, so

$$ \pi_3(f_i) : \pi_3(SU(2)) \to \pi_3(SU(2)) $$

is multiplication by $i$.